# Unallocated small chunks being created in GParted when resizing partitions

Tags: gparted

This might seem very trivial. Whenever I am resizing/deleting partitions in GParted Partition Editor there are always these 1.00 MiB unallocated chunks being created in between which is giving me difficulties when I am trying to merge two partitions in between which these small unallocated chunks of memory are present. I tried merging it with another partition but am not able to. it is pretty annoying. Any solutions to this

I ran the function `sudo parted -l` and did not find those unallocated chunks but here it is[image]

But these are the chunks I am talking about [image]

Comment: Can you append the output of the command `sudo parted -l` to your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is normal!

- Disk partitioning changed a while back to aligning partitions on 1MB boundaries (which improves performance on some modern hard disks and RAID arrays; [IBM has an in-depth article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-4kb-sector-disks/index.html) on it).
- Logical partitions require one sector prior to each defined partition for a necessary data structure.

If you do not want them: change the alignment options. Parted nowadays has options to align partitions to the cylinder, to 1MB marks, or not at all.

2 other methods to get rid them:

- Primary partitions do not need the extra sector and can be aligned with no gaps;  MBR only supports four primary partitions, so this isn't an option for all disks.
- Switch to GPT (GUID Partition Table): it supports up to 128 partitions by default  and does not require space between partitions.

Comment: That was informative!